# Azure - Logic app to Service Bus - JSON transfer

Tags: json, azure, azureservicebus, azure-logic-apps

I want to transfer below mentioned JSON response received from http event in **Azure Logic App** to **Azure Service Bus queue**.

```
{
  "properties": {
    "data": {
      "properties": {
        "alertContext": {
          "properties": {},
          "type": "object"
        },
        "essentials": {
          "properties": {
            "alertContextVersion": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "alertId": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "alertRule": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "alertTargetIDs": {
              "items": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "type": "array"
            },
            "description": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "essentialsVersion": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "firedDateTime": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "monitorCondition": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "monitoringService": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "originAlertId": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "resolvedDateTime": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "severity": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "signalType": {
              "type": "string"
            }
          },
          "type": "object"
        }
      },
      "type": "object"
    },
    "schemaId": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "type": "object"
}
```

I have used many expressions like `encodebase64(string(triggerBody()))` but it throws error.

```
ExpressionEvaluationFailed. The execution of template action 'For_each' failed: the result of the evaluation of 'foreach' expression '@encodebase64(string(triggerBody()))' is of type 'String'. The result must be a valid array.
```

Here are the images:

1. json response received by logic as webhook: https://github.com/arindam-b/images/blob/master/Logicapp1.PNG
2. Expression in step, to convert json to string, but is looking for foreach: https://github.com/arindam-b/images/blob/master/Logicapp2.PNG
3. Step 2 full view with service bus part: https://github.com/arindam-b/images/blob/master/Logicapp3.PNG

Many thanks for your valuable inputs.

Comment: Do you want to transfer the whole json data as a queue message?

Comment: Yes. Because all fields are important. Client wants to save it as well for future reference.

Comment: Any update on this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, your JSON response is in `application/json`, the you could be able to do for_each action, it will be like the below pic. And suppose you want to send message to Service Bus.
The For_each input is `triggerbody()` and the message content depends you requirement select the property in you json data. My test content is the `body` property so it should be `items('Fior_each')['body']`.

[image]

The second scene is your json response in  text/plain or other types, in this situation It won't work you use `Request Body JSON Schema`. You have to parse them to json type then select property. The flow will be like the below pic. The `Parse_JSON` input is `triggerbody()` and the `for_each` input is `body('Parse_JSON')`.

[image]

Before I ask did you want to transfer the whole json to message, you affirm it however from your description and your picture, you want to cut your json data and select the property  you want. So if you want to store the whole json, you could store it without schema.

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201100/discussion-on-answer-by-george-chen-azure-logic-app-to-service-bus-json-tran).